# Magento 2 :- What is difference between custom modules and extensions

Tags: magento2, module, extensions

please explain me in full way what difference between custom module and extensions with simple one example

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between modules and extensions is summarised well here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2183909/7823264

Comment: Thanks for answer But  explain me full way with one example